# After running for 4 years I now get a "Invalid use of Null" error in my MS Access 2010 Database

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Out of the blue I have started getting an "Invalid Use of Null". This is now happening on a number of unrelated queries in my database. (MS Access 2010)

The SQL code behind one of the queries is:

```
INSERT INTO [Vendor List] ( [Vendor Number], [Vendor Name] )
SELECT [2_Onbase_NewVendors].[Vendor Number], [2_Onbase_NewVendors].[Vendor Name]
FROM 2_Onbase_NewVendors LEFT JOIN [Vendor List] ON [2_Onbase_NewVendors].[Vendor Number] = [Vendor List].[Vendor Number]
WHERE ((([2_Onbase_NewVendors].[Vendor Name]) Is Null));
```

The query is simply looking for a missing "Vendor" and adding it in.    This has been working perfectly for the last few years.  I had a look at the two tables and at the moment there are no nulls being returned as everything actually matches.

I have checked the references, and they all seem to be correct.  There are no "missing" references. This is happening, in both the runtime, and full versions. I am running the full Access version on Windows 10, where those on the runtime version are running Windows 7. We have recently applied Microsoft office updates, but I cant find anything in those that are related. I've spent a few hours surfing the net but can't find anything relevant. Most things on the net appear to be from when people are creating the queries. I have run the compact and repair on both the front and backend databases.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I assume that at least your data has changed in the last four years. So my bet is that it's a data issue.

Comment: Hi Nick, I have checked the data and can find no issue with the data.  There are no nulls in the data set at the moment anyway.  so I expect the above query to return nothing.  As mentioned this is happening on a number of similarly structured queries.  Some currently should return a null based on the current data and some wont.  All are giving me the same error.   My initial feeling is it is related the windows / office  updates our IT team  rolled out last week,  but trying to track down what references / DLL's etc. were updated is not a simple process

Comment: It would be really handy to be able to rollback windows and confirm your theory

Comment: Can you check if there are any records returning to this query Select * from [2_Onbase_NewVendors] where [2_Onbase_NewVendors].[Vendor Name]) Is Null   , if yes, then you should change your query to check Null for ID and not Name..... a correct suggestion by John Bingham as below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm inclined to say "Thank Microsoft" - but the query does look a little screwy:

The query is selecting data from the table 2_Onbase_NewVendors and inserting it into the table [Vendor List] - but only where 2_Onbase_NewVendors.[Vendor Name] is null?

Shouldn't this be where [Vendor List].[Vendor Number] is null? (or Vendor Name):

```
INSERT INTO [Vendor List] ([Vendor Number], [Vendor Name])
SELECT nv.[Vendor Number], nv.[Vendor Name]
FROM 2_Onbase_NewVendors nv LEFT JOIN [Vendor List] vl ON nv.[Vendor Number] = vl.[Vendor Number]
WHERE vl.[Vendor Number] IS NULL
```

Recommend you always alias tables (as I have done here), as it always improves clarity, both for yourself, and others who have to read your code.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  The purpose of the query is to check if there are new vendors being imported in a daily transaction load,  "Onbase_NewVendors",  that don't exist in the my master  "Vendor List".    If it finds something in the Onbase_NewVendors list that isn't in the Vendor List then it adds the vendor into the Vendor List.   This in turn sets a flag that alerts the team to validate the new Vendor details.   Thanks for the tip on Alias's.  I hadn't seen that before.  I still get the same error when using your SQL.

Comment: Don't ask me how or why but the problem has now disappeared!   14th reboot of PC did the trick!   Definitely put this one down to Microsoft updates